# problem with unformatable usb flash

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, live-usb, flash

I've a problem with my usb flash, this flash had a bootable sabayon installation on it before, and it worked, but when I write ubuntu 14.10 with startup disk creator on this usb, and tried to install it, my laptop dosen't loaded anymore(I could run ubuntu 14.10 live with this usb flash before install it), and know that I'm trying to format this usb flash with ubuntu live, I've this problem u see in screenshot I uploaded
how can I format it ? in addition I used Gparted but problem not solved :-/

the s.s : 
http://i60.tinypic.com/xblmdf.jpg